How to store dynamically data in a PHP callback function
In my WP plugin, I need to store array from a JSON file.
PHP callback retrieve $_POST['some key'] and return to jquery ajax echo sub array json_encode(array['some key']).

First time : $my_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true)) and return to jquery ajax echo json_encode(my_array)
Second time : $my_array = my_array[$_POST['some key']] return to jquery ajax echo json_encode(my_array)
Third time :


$my_array = my_array[$_POST['some other key']] return json_encode(my_array)


How to store value of my_array to avoid global variable ? I read that global variable is not a good way. It's same with $filename ...

The thing to understand about php is that the memory is completely blanked out after each request, so you will need to save that data in a file or a database between requests.
